# How to upload encrypted file to Laravel server

Tags: laravel, encryption, .net-core, aes

I am trying to encrypt a file and then upload it to my Laravel server, decrypt it there and store on the disk. On client-side I'm using `AesManaged` (.NET 5) to encrypt my file. The file is then uploaded to the server through its REST API and RestSharp.

On the server, I'm using built-in `Crypt::decrypt()`, which according to [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption) should support AES. I'm using `APP_KEY` from my `.env` file to generate encryption key on client-side.

For some reason, Laravel fails to decrypt the uploaded file and throws exception saying:

> The payload is invalid.

Has anyone handled this before? What am I missing?

Comment: So every client would have the same key (form the `.env`) for encryption ? Also make sure both side use the same AES cipher, in `config/app.php` the default value for laravel is     `AES-256-CBC`

Comment: Yes. Is that a problem? I'm just encrypting the file because I need to prevent it from being edit or modified. (sorry, encryption is not my strong area. i hear that they want u to generate keys on the fly; haven't tried that yet as I'm stuck on a more basic issue right now)

Comment: you can use this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption#using-the-encrypter

Comment: you said *edit or modified* by who ? Mitm ? Users ?

Comment: @ml59: Yes. The client app needs to store the file on client's machine temporarily before it is successfully uploaded (if it fails, client app will try uploading again after a while). During this time we want to ensure that the file is not read or modified in any way, so we are storing it in encrypted form.

Comment: So using the same key for all users is not safe. User A (or someone who knows the key) could decrypt the file of User B, alter it, and then re-encrypt it.  User B will then upload the altered file without anyone noticing it. The key should be unique per users at least. Also consider implemting some key rotation if the key has been compromised. This is still not perfect but it will gives you enough security i guess

Comment: @ml59: Thanks. I'll look into using different keys. Also, how do I set cipher length to 256 on client-side? Doesn't `AesManaged` limit it to 128? Do I need to switch to `Rijndael` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cross language encryption decryption then laravel inbuilt Encrypter class will fail to decrypt due to mismatch in encryption keys. I will not recommend you to use laravel key in another platform.
For user level encryption make a column in your users table in database and try to store different encryption keys for each user.
To decrypt you can [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib).

```
protected function AESDecrypt($data)
{
    $aes = new \phpseclib\Crypt\AES(1);
    /**
    MODE_ECB = 1;
    MODE_CBC = 2;
    MODE_CFB = 3;
    **/
    $aes->setKeyLength(128);    // Valid key lengths are 128, 192, and 256
    $aes->setKey($this->KEY);  // replace key
    $aes->disablePadding();
    $decryptedData = $aes->decrypt(base64_decode($data));
    return $decryptedData;
}
```